# How to implement Mesibo on Angular 13 app

Tags: angular, mesibo

'm trying to implement Mesibo on a angular 2+ app.
it doesn’t have a lot of docs samples for angular also an npm package is not available, currently, I am converting the JS code on the documentation to typescript for angular implementation.

I successfully connect on Mesibo SDK now facing an error on MesiboListener. how can i apply this to my ts file. Thanks!

I create mesibo.js file in my assets then paste the mesibo js functions and import it on the inde.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MesiboSample</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    
    **<script src="assets/mesibo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>**
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

on app.ts i declare the Mesibo and initialize it on nOnInit

```
declare var Mesibo: any;
  api: any;
  profile: any

  token = '54a7499f41b57ff53564260e9a8bceca4599********';
  app_id = '****';


  ngOnInit(): void {
       this.api = new Mesibo();

       this.api.addListener(this.MesiboListener());
       this.api.setAppName(this.app_id);
       this.api.setAccessToken(this.token);
       this.api.setDatabase("mesibo");

       this.api.start();
      this.profile = this.api.getProfile('2677684');
      console.log(this.profile)


      let m = this.profile.newMessage();
      m.message = "Hello angular";
      m.send();
  }


 MesiboListener(){
    this.api.MesiboListener.prototype.prototype.Mesibo_onConnectionStatus = function(status:any, value: any) {
      console.log("Mesibo_onConnectionStatus: "  + status);
    }
    
    this.api.prototype.Mesibo_onMessageStatus = function(m: any) {
      console.log("Mesibo_onMessageStatus: from "  
          + m.peer + " status: " + m.status);
    }
    
    this.api.prototype.Mesibo_onMessage = function(m: any) {
      console.log("Mesibo_onMessage: from "  + m.peer);
    }
  }
```

I successfully connect on mesibo sdk. my problem is the MesiboListener how to declare it. on this implementation this.api.MesiboListener.prototype is undefined. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not defining `MesiboListener` correctly.

Please change your code as below. We also uploaded basic sample with Angular 13 on https://github.com/mesibo/samples/tree/master/js/angular

```
ngOnInit(): void {
       this.api = new Mesibo();

       this.api.addListener(this);
       this.api.setAppName(this.app_id);
       this.api.setAccessToken(this.token);
       this.api.setDatabase("mesibo");

       this.api.start();


  }

Mesibo_onConnectionStatus(status, value) {
        console.log("Mesibo_onConnectionStatus: "  + status);
}

Mesibo_onMessageStatus = function(m) {
        console.log("Mesibo_onMessageStatus: from "  + m.peer + " status: " + m.status + " id: " + m.mid);
}

Mesibo_onMessage = function(m) {
        console.log("Mesibo_onMessage: from "  + m.peer + " id: " + m.mid + " msg: " + m.message);
}
```

Comment: Big thanks to the Mesibo community for answering my question! hope it has an npm package soon.